# I want to select customer as well as date filter in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the query for select between dates by customer below but it shows error as

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'brand1' in /path on line 92' at line 2

```
$query ="
SELECT * 
  FROM fuelinv 
  WHERE  `billdate` BETWEEN '$from1' AND '$to1' 
    AND `cusname` = '$brand1' 
";
```

Comment: echo/print your actual $query content and fuelinv ddl

Comment: echo $query; - But it looks like an injection error. Always escape data prior to submission. Better yet, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '' around your variables. When using "" string in php you are free to use the variables without any special symbols.